# Get Attachment ID from URL

Tags: images, attachments

I have the URL of an image which I know is an attachment. Now, I need to find out the attachment ID.

This is what I've got (thanks to [PippinsPlugins](https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/)):

```
// retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
        return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

This works fine for an URL like this: 
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/picture.png

My problem is, the URL is the URL of a cropped picture, so it is
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/picture-300x297.png

My next problem is right now, I can't simply explode the URL to remove 300x297, since I might have pictures, which are not cropped but might have a file name like `'picture2-dontexplodeme.png'`

Basically, I need a fool proof solution haha. If there is anyone out there, who has an easy solution, I would be very happy :)

Comment: Is doing it from the CSS (easiest client side with jQuery) an option? e.g. images that have been inserted into posts with the *Add Media* button will typically have a class like `wp-image-123`, indicating the attachment ID.  If the images are inserted automatically elsewhere in the theme, could you add a CSS class or a data attribute containing the ID?

Comment: @ialocin yes, I would call it a duplicate. Perfect solution, from there I can go on. thanks

Comment: My pleasure. I just remembered there is a good answer to a similar question already. Thats why we still need humans, because the system isn't smart enough - yet :)

Comment: You can use core function `attachment_url_to_postid()`

Answer (score 2):

```php
function get_attachment_id_from_src ($image_src) {

    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$image_src'";
    $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    return $id;

}
```

Comment: Is something like this useful?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this doesn't apply on cropped images like http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/picture-300x297.png since their URL are not stored like this in the database.

Comment: Can you post a link to the real website?

Comment: You could also just hardcode the image into your page. If you can show me what you are trying to do I might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: thanks for your help. the community found the answer for what i was looking for. your help is still appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you and glad you could find an answer ^^ Could you post the code you are using? I'd like to see what you are doing just out of interest. I much around with WordPress every day but it's always nice seeing different ways to solve different problems.

Comment: With the ID you can get any size using the  `wp_get_attachment_image_src() ` function. Example: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, $size); ` then echo the URL: `echo $img_object[0];`